# Strong wireless signal yet apparently randomly no internet connection. Other devices work through wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, internet-connection

My daughter's laptop (Windows 7 - fully updated) gets a strong wireless signal yet apparently randomly cannot get an internet connection.
It's not truly random.  So it's always worked in my home.  It always worked where she lived previously.  Some coffee shops and similar places offering internet to the general public don't work.

She's now moved to a new place, brand new Sky router.  Wired internet works from laptop, wireless internet did not work from laptop although laptop sported 5 bars of signal.  Wireless internet does work for her tablet and her chromecast.
We could ping the router, via wireless, from the laptop although there was surprising packet loss (order of 50% but on very small volumes). 
This suggests that IP is working fine and seems (to me) to prove that there is wireless connection the wireless passwords etc all look fine and at least the lower end of the IP stack is working fine.
The upper end of the IP stack seems fine because everything works fine with a wired connection and everything works fine with some (but not all) other wireless networks.

We used window remote assistance.  I connected to her machine and looked at all the router settings I could find.  I didn't see anything that looked out of the ordinary and certainly nothing that would distinguish her laptop from her tablet.  She hadn't fiddled with any of the settings.  It's truly plug and play - as it was for her other gear.  On the laptop I looked at her wireless adapter and IP settings.  I didn't find anything that looked odd or different to my own laptop.

At this point we discovered that internet was working.  Possibly relevant; pings to the router had much lower packet loss.

Today (about 24hours later) there is a strong wireless signal but no internet connection.

I'm stumped.  The common factor is clearly the laptop yet the laptop has no problem with the wireless part of the connection reports successful connection and strong signal.  It looks like the connection to the internet is blocked by the router, but why would it single out the laptop?  Why is there a random population of other routers (in coffee shops etc) that also single out this laptop?

Any ideas for further research?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your home router is broadcasting at G or N and her wireless card isn't compatible, can she see the SSID of the router on the list?

Look into what type of signal your router uses (802.11/b/g or whatever) and then compare that with with the types supported by the wireless card in her laptop.

Comment: I don't think this can be it.  All of these suggest permanent failure.  The laptop shows 5 bars of signal.  We are beyond just seeing the router's SSID.  It's connected, agreed that it has the appropriate encryption key, and we can ping to the router.  Add to that it sometimes works.